# WPF Prism how to have duplicate views inside a region

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm currently working with the Tab control and have created a region so it will become my host.

what I'm trying to do is add the same view to a region twice.. you may ask why? and its because the application is going a simple chat app - there will many instances of the view but each will have different information.

my code so far;;

```
        IConversationDetailsPresentationModel convDetailsView1 =
            this.Container.Resolve<IConversationDetailsPresentationModel>();

        IRegionManager manager = this.Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();

        manager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TabRegion", () => convDetailsView1);

        IConversationDetailsPresentationModel convDetailsView2 =
            this.Container.Resolve<IConversationDetailsPresentationModel>();

        manager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TabRegion", () => convDetailsView2);
```

And my views are registered with unity like so;;

```
   this.Container.RegisterType<IConversationDetailsPresentationModel,                   ConversationDetailsPresentationModel>(
            new TransientLifetimeManager());

        this.Container.RegisterType<IConversationDetailsView, ConversationDetailsView>(
            new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

also, my XAML

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left"
            Width="Auto"
            Height="Auto"
            cal:RegionManager.RegionName="TabRegion"
            Name="TabRegion"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="TabContentRegion">

            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

**Edit : my actual question is this.. Is it possible to have duplicate views inside a region? When I try it currently I get an exception about it already being registered.. what I really need is to  bypass this or possible create a region that will allow it.**

thanks for any help!!

cheers.
ste.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Didn't you just write your own answer to your question. "A region is attached to a UI element such as a **ContentControl**, **ItemsControl**, **TabControl**, or a customer control, and manages the UI element's content". So yeah it should work.

Comment: @Rikkos - please see my updated comment.. what I'm basically looking for is to have duplicate views inside my region!

Comment: just a troubleshooting idea, have you tried GetHashCode() to see if TransientLifetimeManager is giving you different instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
IRegion TabRegion =  manager.Regions["TabRegion"];

tabRegion.Add(convDetailsView1);
tabRegion.Add(convDetailsView2);
```

Comment: That didn't work sadly - it gave the follow error .. "{"Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first."}"

Comment: Wait, duplicate as in EXACTLY the same, or of the same type. I dont see you using the same instance. I've made a test project and I dont have any problems. I've tried everything. I can take a look at your project if you have it available. that would be a last option to help you

Comment: Same type really - they should be there own instance of the view/presentation model just with different data..

Comment: @Stephen Well I can't find anything that might cause your problem. The only thing that I can think of is your datatemplate. What are you trying to achieve with the region "TabContentRegion".

Comment: Solved it... somehow.. I had a <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"> which was causing the element already in the tree problem.. after removing that and just adding it in the control everything was fixed

Comment: please see my other question related to this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205063/wpf-prism-region-inside-a-tab-control-isnt-in-the-region-list

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
IRegion TabRegion =  manager.Regions["TabRegion"];
tabRegion.Add(convDetailsView1).AdToRegion("make your region here",convDetailsView2);
```