# WPF Prism Region inside a tab control isn't in the Region List

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, prism, enterprise-library, tabcontrol

I've got a tab control with a region attached to it and I've also got a content control inside my tab controls content with another region.

The problem I'm having is - if I call RegisterViewWithRegion it adds the view to the region no problem (first time that is, get issues if you swap tabs). But this isn't very flexible and I'm looking for a better way to do that.

When I look inside IRegionManager.Regions as well - I can only see the two top level regions. I cant see my sub region **TabContentRegion**.  Is there a way to register this so I can just work in the usual way with adding views and activating them?

```
   <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left"
            Width="Auto"
            Height="Auto"
            cal:RegionManager.RegionName="TabRegion"
            Name="TabRegion"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <ContentControls:TransitionContentControl 
                cal:RegionManager.RegionName="TabContentRegion" />

        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

This code adds the views to the TabRegion

```
 public void Load()
 {
     IConfigurationDetailsPresentationModel convDetailsView1 =
         this.Container.Resolve<IConfigurationDetailsPresentationModel>();

     IRegionManager manager = this.Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
     manager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TabRegion", () => convDetailsView1);

     IConversationDetailsPresentationModel conversationDetails = 
         this.Container.Resolve<IConversationDetailsPresentationModel>();
     manager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TabRegion", () => conversationDetails);
 }
```

Then this is the code I've been using to actually display the view in the TabContentRegion

```
 public IPresentationModel SelectedTab
 {
     get { return _selectedTab; }
     set
     {
         _selectedTab = value;

         IRegionManager service = this.Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();

         if (service != null)
         {
             service.RegisterViewWithRegion(
                 "TabContentRegion",
                 () => _selectedTab.View);
         }
     }
 }
```

As you can see - it's a bit janky and doesn't quite work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of playing and googling I finally came across and answer!

because the region was inside a datatemplate, that ment that prisms standard behaviours wouldn't pick it up and register it with the region manager.

using the code provided [here](http://blogs.southworks.net/dcherubini/2011/11/10/regions-inside-datatemplates-in-prism-v4-using-a-region-behavior/) it helped me to fix this and carry on as normal! :)

cheers.
ste.